# XP translate IP address of outbound traffic

Tags: networking, windows-xp, nat

On Windows XP, I have a program that is trying to hit a hardcoded IP address (10.x.x.x), meant to be on a certain LAN. But my machine is on the 192.x.x.x network. I want to redirect this outbound traffic going to 10.x.x.x to a different IP so the program works. 
Can I do this at the windows-level?

Comment: You need a host in the network of 10.0.0.0/8 and then use that as gateway for the net. With a separate NIC on the XP host you can configure that to be in the 10.0.0.0/8 net.

Comment: What protocol is it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little "ugly" in setup, but should work without the need for additional hardware:

1. Setup an additional IP assignment on your current NIC configuration which is the actual hard-coded destination address
2. Download and install http://analogx.com/contents/download/Network/pmapper/Freeware.htm
3. Configure PortMapper to suit your needs